Tkinter in Python
I am learning Tkinter from an online recorded course. I was given a task to build this small GUI using Tkinter.
I am getting this:

My code:
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx= 20,pady=20)

canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200) #, highlightthickness=0
password_logo = PhotoImage(file= 'logo.png')
canvas.create_image(100,100,image=password_logo)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)

Website_Label = Label(text="Website:")
Website_Label.grid(column=0, row=1)
Email_Label = Label(text="Email/Username:")
Email_Label.grid(column=0, row=2)
Password_Label = Label(text="Password:")
Password_Label.grid(column=0, row=3)

entry_1 = Entry(width=35)
entry_1.grid(column=1, row=1,columnspan=2)
entry_2 = Entry(width=35)
entry_2.grid(column=1, row=2,columnspan=2)
entry_3 = Entry(width=21)
entry_3.grid(column=1, row=3)

gen_pass_button = Button(text="Generate Password")
gen_pass_button.grid(column=2, row=3)
add_button = Button(text="Add",width=36)
add_button.grid(column=1, row=4,columnspan=2)
window.mainloop()



Expected output:

I shall obtain the above output. The instructor's code and my code is same. She used MacOS and I use windows 11 Pycharm.

Learn more on The Grid Geometry Manager

Look up the sticky argument for .grid(...). Also if you want more advanced resizing based on the window size, look at the .grid_columnconfigure and .grid_rowconfigure methods.

Thank you so much for the suggestion of using sticky in the .grid() method. It works perfectly now. I have set the value to sticky = "EW" wherever required and the output looks exactly like I wanted it to be.
